# Can I use CSS @media in an iFrame to respond to the viewport width of the parent?

Tags: css, iframe, media-queries

I have a page with a central iFrame flanked by two sidebars left/right, and I am trying to make the iFrame's content responsive. I already have the parent window set up with @media queries in the CSS stylesheet, so that it changes the layout when the viewport width is reduced (I'm working PC screen down, not mobile screen up). This layout change is (among others) a switching of the sidebars from left/right to top/bottom relative to the center iFrame for the mobile view.

The issue is the iFrame's viewport. When I use @media's max-width in the iFrame's CSS sheet, it uses the inner width of the iFrame as viewport width. This is causing me trouble because when switching the sidebars in the parent window to top/bottom positions, the iFrame's size goes from ~540px in the smallest desktop view to ~860px in the largest mobile view, so I can't set a @media max-width query without creating an overlap on either side - displaying either the PC-intended iFrame CSS on the mobile parent CSS, or vice versa.

I would also prefer not to use max-device-width instead, because then the content no longer responds to resizing of the *browser* window on a PC, since it refers to the screen size rather than the browser window size. (This is important to me because it allows me to quickly test the responsiveness and allows for people using the page on a non-maximised browser page.)

Is there a way to make an iFrame's content responsive to the size of the parent window, rather than itself or the screen?

I have control over all the elements involved, so if this can't be done I can also change the iFrame into a PHP include statement and put the center panel content on the page that way.